# Not all fields serialized by toJson()

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using `Gson 2.2`'s `toJson()` method  to serialize a java object into a json string. The java object is of type:

```
public class LOB implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private LOBType type; 

    private TypeSpecificData data;

    public class TypeSpecificData {
        private String a;
        private int b;
    } 

}
```

All fields of the object are serialized except for `data` field of type `TypeSpecificData`.

How do I include this field as well in the json string ?

Currently I'm serializing like shown below:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(lob_instance);
```

Comment: I simply use this to serialize : `new Gson().toJson(lob_instance);`

Comment: Do you initialize data field? if it's null, it will not serialized

Comment: yeah.. found that  field was not getting initialized due to some reasons.. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Gson will not serialize null objects refereces. Please check it.

[Link to GSON documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support)

Comment: ohk .. yes that field was not getting initialized due to some reasons.. Thanks for pointing that out!